# Mongoose: Modeling and updating many to many

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to mongodb and mongoose and I'd like to know how to handle many to many relations. I know mongodb is a non-relational database, but how would I model something like Users and Groups.
A User can join multiple groups while a group can have multiple users.

My Schemas look like this:

User

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },  
    groups: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Group',
        },
    ],
});
```

Group

```
const GroupSchema: Schema = new Schema({    
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
    ],
});
```

So, with an endpoint like 'users/:id/assigngroup/:groupid I would like to add an User_id to User.groups and the groupid to Group.users.

For my endpoint I do something like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { $addToSet: { groups: groupId } }, { new: true }).populate('groups').exec((err, user) => {            
     Group.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: groupId }, { $addToSet: { users: _id } }, { new: true }).exec((err, group) => {                
         res.send(user);
    });
})
```

This works tho, but the problems I encountered are:

- I could still add a groupId to User.users even if the Group with this id doesn't exist. I could check this with an additional Group.findOne() before the User.findOneAndUpate but this doesn't feel like it's the best/quickest way in mongoose.
- How should I handle a rollback if, for example one of the findOneAndUpdate, fails?

What I need is a clean way to check if the Group with the groupid exists, then check if the user with the _id exists and after that I can add the groupid to User.groups and the _id to Group.users (and not being able to add the same id multiple times of course). What would be the best way to do this? Using findOne/findOneUpdate mutiple times for each check doesn't feel like the right way.

Please let me know if my approach to model this "relation" is completely wrong.

Thanks! :)

**Edit**: I don't think it's the smart way to save a reference in both models. I removed groups from the User model. So to assign a User I just use

```
Group.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: groupId }, { $addToSet: { users: _id } }, { new: true }).populate('users', '_id username').exec().then(group => {  });
```

And the easy way to get all Groups of a User would be

```
Group.find({
        "users": new Types.ObjectId(id)
    }).exec(callback);
```

So I don't need to update a reference twice if I assign/remove a User.